# PowerBook G4 boots into blue screen with cursor

Tags: macos, powerbook

I have an 1.5GHz PowerBook G4 running OS X 10.5.8. I can only boot to the safe mode. I cannot get a normal boot. It stops at a blue screen with a cursor. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try booting your computer into verbose mode. Hold Command (⌘) and V together at boot. What does it get stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

First, boot the machine in Safe Mode and check to see what your available space is on your hard drive.  If it is low, I suggest freeing up at least 1GB of space.  That will sometimes work.  Other times, I've had to repair the volume using disk utility from an installation disk.  As a last effort (if you have the space, and a backup) do an archive install once you've verified that the hard drive does not have any bad sectors or issues with the volume in disk utility.  Good luck!